# C++: Reading and comparing from command line

Tags: c++, command-line, compare, arrays

I'm reading a line from the command line that looks like this:

`"./test -C original.txt compressed.txt"`

The variable `-C` can also be `-D` (it is irrelevant to state what they mean).

I want to verify within my code that it is one of those two options, but I'm having trouble using the `argv[]` character array within my code.

Here's what I'm trying in my if statement:

`if((strcmp(av[1], "-C") == 0)||(strcmp(av[1], "-c") == 0))`

I've also tried directly comparing the values

`if((av[1] == "-C") || (av[1] == "-c"))`

Comment: Have you tried printing `av[1]`?

Comment: Yeah and it prints `-C`, which is correct

Comment: Have you tried printing the return value of `strcmp`?

Comment: if((strcmp(av[1], "-C") == 0)||(strcmp(av[1], "-c") == 0)) looks fine

Comment: Use `getopts`. Always use `getopts` :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are in c++ its better to use `std::string`:

```
if((std::string(argv[1]) == "-C") || (std::string(argv[1]) == "-c"))
```

if its still not working try to print the variable and see if its what you are expecting.

Comment: @Lady_ari If this answer solved your problem, accepting is the way to go. If you don't know what I'm talking about and how this Q&A site works, looking into the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) should be your first action.

Answer (score 1):

If `main()`'s prototype is `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`, then the correct way to check if the first argument is either "-c" or "-C", without using `std::string`s is

```
if((strcmp(argv[1], "-C") == 0)||(strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0))
   // do things
```

You may need to `#include <cstring>` to make use of `strcmp()`

Comment: I did that, but it didn't work.
I used `std::string`, so it works now

Answer (score 0):

```
if((argv[1] == "-C") || (argv[1] == "-c"))
```

this couldn't work as argv[1] is pointing to a specific array of characters wich contains the first command-line argument. on the other side "-c" is a constant pointer to a specific other array of charaters wich contains "-C"

so this doesn't compare the values those pointers are actually pointing to, it compares the addresses of the two arrays wich will most likely be different in any case i could imagine...